# Find two strings using regex in any order

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

For example I have an input: `"Test your Internet connection bandwidth. Test your Internet connection bandwidth."` (two times repeated) and I want to search for strings **internet** and **bandwidth**.

```
string keyword = tbSearch.Text //That holds value: "internet bandwidth"
string input = "Test your Internet connection bandwidth. Test your Internet connection bandwidth.";

Regex r = new Regex(keyword.Replace(' ', '|'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (r.Matches(input).Count == siteKeyword.Split(' ').Length)
{
    //Do something
}
```

This doesn't work cause it finds 2 "internet" and 2 "bandwidth", so it count 4 but the keyword length is 2. So what I can do?

Comment: If you just want search for 'internet' and 'bandwidth' why are you using this complex code? Is there something more you want to do?

Comment: I just used 2 keywords at this example he can give more

Comment: What are you trying to do? To check if all keywords in your input string?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes exactly what you said

Comment: So the question is how many keywords appear in a given string, but each only counts once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var pattern = keyword.Split()
        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                   (sb, s) => sb.AppendFormat(@"(?=.*\b{0}\b)", Regex.Escape(s)),
                   sb => sb.ToString());

if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // contains all keywords
}
```

First part is generating pattern from your keywords. If there is two keywords `"internet bandwidth"`, then generated regex pattern will look like:

`"(?=.*\binternet\b)(?=.*\bbandwidth\b)"`

It will match following inputs:

```
"Test your Internet connection bandwidth."
"Test your Internet connection bandwidth. Test your Internet bandwidth."
```

Following inputs will not match (not all words contained):

```
"Test your Internet2 connection bandwidth bandwidth."
"Test your connection bandwidth."
```

---

Another option (verifying each keyword separately):

```
var allWordsContained = keyword.Split().All(word => 
    Regex.IsMatch(input, String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(word)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ well, actually he wants to know that all words contained in string (`count` is just a way he tried to do that), so I think it will do as is :)

Comment: +1 As a matter of good practice, you should escape the keywords in case they ever contain a special character: `sb.AppendFormat(@"(?=.*\b{0}\b)", Regex.Escape(s))`

Comment: @Cyborgx37 agree, fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Guys you are the best... I don't know if other answers works but this works great...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you could try something like this:

```
public bool allWordsContained(string input, string keyword)
{
    bool result = true;
    string[] words = keyword.Split(' ');

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (!input.Contains(word))
            result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

public bool atLeastOneWordContained(string input, string keyword)
{
    bool result = false;
    string[] words = keyword.Split(' ');

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (input.Contains(word))
            result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Clue is to get a list of results and make Distinct()...

```
    string keyword = "internet bandwidth";
    string input = "Test your Internet connection bandwidth. Test your Internet connection bandwidth.";

    Regex r = new Regex(keyword.Replace(' ', '|'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(input);
    List<string> res = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count;i++ )
    {
        res.Add(mc[i].Value);
    }

    if (res.Distinct().Count() == keyword.Split(' ').Length)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex(keyword.Replace(' ', '|'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
int distinctKeywordsFound = r.Matches(input)
                             .Cast<Match>()
                             .Select(m => m.Value)
                             .Distinct()
                             .Count();
if (distinctKeywordsFound == siteKeyword.Split(' ').Length)
{
    //Do something
}
```